# что значит "Из платья выросла девочка"

Tags: выражения

"Из дома вдруг вышла Даша - красивая девочка с огромными белыми бантами и в зеленом платье, из которого она тоже уже, по-моему,выросла."

Скажите пожалуйста,как понимать выражение "из платья выросла девочка"?
это имеется в виду, что платье старое. Оно уже маленькое для нее. Или тут еще другие значения. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы поняли значение фразы правильно!

Answer (score 5):

Это значит, что платье уже не по ней, то есть Даша уже великовата для него. Тут скорее всего имеется ввиду, что платье уже не подходит по **размеру**. Но, возможно, само платье слишком детское (по **дизайну**).

Answer (score 4):

Мы не говорим "из платья выросла девочка", мы говорим "девочка выросла из платья". 
Первое бы значило, что было платье, а потом из него, как растение их семечки, выросла девочка, а второе - что девочка стала больше, а платье осталось маленьким, и теперь оно ей мало.

Точно так же дети вырастают из штанишек, любой другой одежды.

> -Чудеса! - сказала Люба.-
>
> Шуба длинная была,
>
> В сундуке лежала шуба,
>
> Стала шуба мне мала. (Агния Барто, 1969)

Аналогично мы вырастаем из чего-то в переносном смысле. "Мы уже выросли из поверхностного подхода к бизнесу" - означает, что раньше мы практиковали поверхностный подход, но сейчас мы сильно продвинулись, и больше так не делаем.

Comment: В разговорной речи легко могу представить что кто-то скажет "ооо, из платья-то выросла уже девочка"

Comment: @shabunc , в разговорной - безусловно. Но интонация играет роль. )

Answer (score 0):

It is a pun (каламбур), actually: выйти из дома means literally "leave home", and вырасти из платья means that the dress is too small for her. As both phrases have totally different sense but common structure (verb + preposition из meaning from, or out of, + noun in genitive case), a comical/pun effect is reached here.

Comment: It might be a pun in some case, but I don't see it in this particular sentence.